# passing a value to a function in a different class from a FileObserver in Android giving NO EMPTY CONSTRUCTOR error

Tags: android

I am trying to pass a value to a function from FileObserver to an activity as follows -

```
public class MyFileObserver extends FileObserver 
{
public String absolutePath;
final FileEvent fileevent  = new FileEvent(this);

final filehelper f_help = new filehelper(fileevent);
public MyFileObserver(String path) 
{
    super(path, FileObserver.ALL_EVENTS);
    absolutePath = path;
}

@Override
public void onEvent(int event, String path) 
{
    if (path == null) 
    {
        return;
    }
    //a new file or subdirectory was created under the monitored directory
    if ((FileObserver.CREATE & event)!=0) 
    {
        FileAccessLogStatic.accessLogMsg += absolutePath + "/" + path + " is created\n";
        Log.v(path+ " in FileObserver ====>>>> ",path);
        fileevent.insert(path);         
    }}}
```

And this is the code for insert() in FileEvent class-

```
public class FileEvent extends ListActivity{
public String filename;

final adapter info = new adapter (this);
public FileEvent(MyFileObserver myFileObserver) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

public void insert(String path) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    this.filename = path;
      int rowcount = info.getrowcountofpersons(); 

       Log.v("rowcount in new list onCreate: ", ""+info.getrowcountofpersons()+"");
       String[] values = new String[rowcount];
       for(int i =1;i<=rowcount;i++)
       {
        values[i-1]=info.getPersonList(i); 
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), values[i-1], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    System.out.println("in for loop now"+values[i-1]);
       }

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        listView.setItemsCanFocus(false);
        listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);


       // Assign adapter to List
        setListAdapter(adapter);  
      //  new Bullet(info).execute((Void)null);
    }}
```

When I run this code, I get the following error in Logcat -

```
09-24 23:53:36.430: E/AndroidRuntime(5870): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.seperate_fileobserver/com.example.seperate_fileobserver.FileEvent}: java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class com.example.seperate_fileobserver.FileEvent; no empty constructor
09-24 23:53:36.430: E/AndroidRuntime(5870):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2137)
09-24 23:53:36.430: E/AndroidRuntime(5870):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
```

This is how, I have registered the service in manifest.xml file -

```
    <service 
        android:enabled="true" 
        android:name="com.example.seperate_fileobserver.FileModificationService">
    </service>
```

Is it possible to start an activity from a service?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must provide an empty constructor of any `Activity` subtype. if you want to make the activity start parametrised - use `intent.putExtra` to add all the parameters you need for the activity.

Comment: Thank you for the reply @Maxim Efimov, I saw the same suggestion in an another question. But the problem is, when I try to insert `Intent` in the `FileObserver`, I am getting the error - `The constructor Intent(MyFileObserver, Class<FileEvent>) is undefined`. So, unable to understand, how to do it. So, if you don't mind, can you please demonstrate it with some sample code?

Comment: @nki do not call an Observer with intent. Call activity or service - actually that's the only two thigs you can start with intent. Put a file name as a String to Intent object, start the activity with the intent, then use the String value from the intent in `onCreate` method of the activity to create an instance of `FileObserver` class.

Comment: No no @Maxim Efimov, I am not calling an Observer from a class, instead I am calling a function on a class from an Observer. I am unable to implement how to do what you said now. I am a newbie to android. Please post a bit of sample code to demonstrate if possible. Please.

Comment: Oh I see now. Actually it's not a good design because lifecycle of an activity is not the same with any other object in an application. Thus you must not rely on the fact that your activity even exist on filechange event is fired. You may want to use a callback technique - do not instance a FileEvent object inside observer class, but pass it as a parameter http://pastebin.com/nudv0hNL the better way is to use `MyFileObserver` as a private non-static class of `FileEvent` class and make an instance of `MyFileObserver` in `onCreate` method of the activity.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @Maxim Efimov, now I am not getting any error in the log. But the Log.v message is not displayed - `Log.v(path+ " in FileObserver ====>>>> ",path);`. What might be the reason for this??

Comment: You should make an instance of `MyFileObserver` inside the `FileEvent`, I think. Read the warning http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/FileObserver.html

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37990/discussion-between-nki-and-maxim-efimov)